# Media Library “HTTP error” when upload finishes

Tags: wordpress

I am uploading zip file from wordpress admin panels **Media Library**, its size is 128MB first and it uploaded successfully. But when i try more than 150 MB its **HTTP errors** show every time.

[image]

Comment: did you checked write permissions for uploads folder

Comment: Yes, I have checked upload folder has 777 permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the upload file size limit in your wp-config or in your php.ini?

Comment: Yes, I have set upload file size 512MB.

Comment: In which file??

Comment: Php.ini file set size limit

Comment: Okay, its possible your internet connection is timing out. What are your upload/download speeds?